# how do I prevent multiple login in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to prevent my users to make a multiple login, once the user login, if the same username login they prompt "account already login in other device."

My **Login Controller**

```
public function login()
{

    $this->logged_in();

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
        // true case
        $email_exists = $this->model_auth->check_email($this->input->post('email'));

        if($email_exists == TRUE) {
            $login = $this->model_auth->login($this->input->post('email'), $this->input->post('password'));

            if($login) {

                $logged_in_sess = array(
                    'id' => $login['id'],
                    'username'  => $login['username'],
                    'email'     => $login['email'],
                    'logged_in' => TRUE
                );

                $this->session->set_userdata($logged_in_sess);
                redirect('dashboard/', 'refresh');
            }
            else {
                $this->data['errors'] = '<b>Signin account failed</b>';
                $this->load->view('login', $this->data);
            }
        }
        else {
            $this->data['errors'] = '<b>Signin account failed</b>';
            $this->load->view('login', $this->data);
        }   
    }
    else {
        // false case
        $this->load->view('login');
    }   
}
```

and i have a table called "ci_session" so that I will store the session on my database.

Hope anybody help me here. Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to track already logged in users using session and cookies.

Whenever a new user tries to login, verify whether any active session is going on for that particular user or not. If an active session is on, you need to check the cookie in session DB, with the current cookie of the user. If no cookie exists, means its a fresh login for the user. If a cookie exists and matches with the one presented by the user, means an active session. If the cookie doesn't match, the user is trying to login from another source. Finally, if it's a fresh login, create and store a cookie in the user's system and ur session DB.

Hopefully, this will help